# Sort array and get first 5 values

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have created an array:

```
var stores = [];
```

I add some info to it with a for each:

```
stores[id] = distance;
```

How can I sort the array stores based on distance and get the first 5 id's and show them on the page?

Thanks!

Comment: [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: What does the data look like? You'll only need to define a custom function if the data is obscure such as an array of objects. Numbers and text should sort fine as is. If the structure is simple then call `stores.sort();`...

Comment: Please include your data as text in the question itself, not as an image on some other site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort), for sorting numbers in descending order you should do this:

```
stores.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
```

Then, if you want to get the first 5 elements, you are probably looking for the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) function.

```
stores.slice(0,5);
```

```js
var arr = []; 
arr['2'] = 50; 
arr['3'] = 173; 
arr['4'] = 198;  
arr['5'] = 273; 
arr['6'] = 68; 
arr['7'] = 7; 
arr['26'] = 21; 

arr = arr.filter(function(item){
    return item !== undefined;
});

arr.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

arr = arr.slice(0,5); 
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It's not sorting on distance? I tried this before.. what does the b-a means?

Comment: @hg96nl It's the way the [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function knows where to place the data. Anything less than `0` means `a` should come before `b`. `0` means leave `a` and `b` unchanged. Anything greater than `0` means `a` should come after `b`. This example though is trivial and will not work on complex data. This is how the `Array.sort()` function works out of the box. To help you further we need to understand the structure of your data...

Comment: @War10ck Hm, it is not working here.. when I use console.log(stores) after this function nothing happend..

Comment: @hg96nl Can't help without seeing the structure of your data. You need to post a sample of what your array looks like...

Comment: Still no luck here.. is it because the array is created with info from a JSON call? I call you code after the JSON call, so I think it's not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is javascript solution:

here is the modified solution

```js
var stores = [ ];
stores['40'] = '152';
stores['22'] = '55';
stores['33'] = '3';
stores['28'] = '2';

console.log(stores)
console.log(stores.sort((a, b) => a - b))
```

Comment: I get an empty alert? Is it because my array?

Comment: Can u provide some fiddle or codepen link to debug ur code

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYXXQd, my array looks like this (in console).

Comment: Thanks, but not working.. I create an array before a JSON call, after that I insert some info from there in the array.. is that problem?

Comment: Make sure that u are using array data after json call or check whether array is getting executed before the json call complete. Try to show the code what  u really working on.

Comment: I edit my post, could you take a look? Exactly I try to sort the stores based on distance.

Comment: I have gone through ur code. First check whether r u getting response in directionService.route() function. If u r getting response then, try to define 'var stores = []' outside the functions.

Comment: Is it possible to run the sort function if this code is done: `data.features.map(function (item)`?

Comment: yes. There seems to be something  missing over there.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?